# For loop to conduct time series on multiple subsets of dataframe and pool summary statistics

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series, linear-regression

I have a dataframe `df` consisting of 40 imputed datasets `imp` each with 228 months `month` of parasitoid frequency `psit` and climatic variability data `var`.

```
set.seed(560)
df<-data.frame(imp= rep(1:40, each=228), month=rep(1:228), psit= 
rep(rnorm(228, 20, 10)), var=rnorm(9120, 50, 10))
```

I would like to loop through each `imp` subset and conduct a series of time lag analyses. The first time lag will be one month offset from the most recent data, the second time lag would be 2 months offset from the most recent data, etc. for a total of 216 months into the past. Here is a example of this for three time lags for the first imputed dataset:

```
sub<-subset(df, imp==1)
timelag1<- cbind(sub[1:12,3], sub[2:13,4]) #1 month time lag
timelag2<- cbind(sub[1:12,3], sub[3:14,4]) #2 month time lag
timelag3<- cbind(sub[1:12,3], sub[4:15,4]) #3 month time lag
```

....so on for all 213 months left.  Thus, there will be multiple time lag analyses for each `imp` subset. Then I will repeat this for all the imputed datasets. From each time lag I want to calculate the r-squared value. If this is done for all 40 imputed datasets I would have 40 r-squared values for timelag 1, 40 r-squared values for timelag 2, 40 r-squared values for timelag 3 ...and so on. So I wish to pool these r-squared values together. Thus at the end of the loop I should have one vector of pooled r-squared values for each time lag.

EXAMPLE:

```
 model_for_timelag1<-lm(psit ~ lag(var, -1), tail(df, 12+1) #lm for 
  timelag1
 summary(model_for_timelag1)$r.squared
 #Repeat model 1 for the 39 remaining imputed datasets

 model_for_timelag2<-lm(psit ~ lag(var, -2), tail(df, 12+2)  #lm for 
 timelag2
 summary(model_for_timelag2)$r.squared
 #Repeat model 2 for the 39 remaining imputed datasets

 model_for_timelag3<-lm(psit ~ lag(var, -3), tail(df, 12+3)  #lm for 
 timelag3
 summary(model_for_timelag3)$r.squared 
 #Repeat model 3 for the 39 remaining imputed datasets

 pool.r.squared(all_model1) #pool all 40(all imputed datasets)model1s
 pool.r.squared(all_model2) #pool all 40(all imputed datasets)model2s
 pool.r.squared(all_model3) #pool all 40(all imputed datasets)model3s
```

My unsuccessful attempt:

```
 rsquared<-NA

 for (i in length(df$imp)) {
 model[i]<- lm(psit ~ lag(var, var[[-i]]), tail(df, 12+var[[i]])
 rsquared[i]<- summary$r.squared
 pool.r.squared()
    }
```

I am not partial to a for loop if there is an easier solution. I just foresee a for-loop as being capable of handling this type of problem.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://github.com/egouldo/many_models/blob/master/many_models.md#when-do-we-fit-multiple-models